# Opencart 2.2: Sending extension name to view

Tags: php, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am using Opencart 2.2

On landing page of my store I have to show featured products of multiple categories , So i have created 4 featured extensions, assigned them products, enabled them, put them on my page form Design->layout->home and it works perfect. But now I have to render Category name in every featured.tpl . The $heading_title variable gets its value from language which is always the word featured.

```
class ControllerExtensionModuleFeatured extends Controller {
public function index($setting) {
    $this->load->language('extension/module/featured');

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
```

I want to display extension name in the view, how can i get extension name in featured controller or featured.tpl

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

So I did some workout and printed the $setting which is sent to the index function and it returned me the name so I added featured_name under the product like this

```
$data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id'  => $product_info['product_id'],
    'thumb'       => $image,
    'name'        => $product_info['name'],
    'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_description_length')) . '..',
    'price'       => $price,
    'special'     => $special,
    'tax'         => $tax,
    'rating'      => $rating,
    'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id'])
);
$data['featured_name']=$setting['name'];
```

And I simply printed $featured_name in view